# How to create array of arrays using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I created an array from a list of values :

```
var valueslist = $('#list .row .amount').map(function () {  
          return $(this).text();  
        }).get();
```

And each value is added to a checkbox :

```
var uniquevalues = [... new Set(valueslist)];
    
    var $dropdown = $(this).find(".filters .options");
    $.each(uniquevalues, function() {
        label = $(this).find()
    $dropdown.append('<div><input type="checkbox" value="' + this + '" checked><label>' + this + '</label></div>')
```

This works fine.

However, the values in question are actually composed of 2 spans :

```
<span class="indexlabel">1 234 €</span>
<span class="indexvalue">1234</span>
```

And my jQuery function, therefore, displays : *1 234 € 1234*.

I would like each checkbox to display :

```
<div><input type="checkbox" value="INDEXVALUE" checked><label>INDEXLABEL</label></div>
```

I tried modifying the jQuery map function :

```
var valueslist = $('#list .row .amount').map(function () {  
    var value = $(this).find('span.indexvalue').text();
    var label = $(this).find('span.indexlabel').text();

    return [value, label];
        }).get();
```

But of course, this doesn't work. What is the correct way to proceed?

Comment: What is `this` in `$(this).find(".filters .options");`?

Answer (score 0):

`return [value, label]` is a good idea, but the jQuery `.map` method will flatten the resulting list, which is undesired. So you'd have to use the native `.map` function instead.

Then the next issue is the creation of the unique values. As now the array is an array of pairs, you can no longer use the `Set` constructor for this. But -- assuming the value part is the key -- you could use the `Map` constructor, and then retrieve the entries from that Map.

For populating `$dropdown` little would have to change, but I would suggest to use jQuery more to the full here:

```js
var valueslist = $('#list .row .amount').get().map((spans) => [  
    $(spans).find('span.indexvalue').text(),
    $(spans).find('span.indexlabel').text()
]);

var uniquevalues = [... new Map(valueslist).entries()];
    
var $dropdown = $(document).find(".filters .options");
$dropdown.append(
    uniquevalues.map(([value, label]) =>
        $('<div>').append(
            $('<label>').append(
                $('<input>', { type: "checkbox", value }),
                label
            )
        )
    )
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="amount">
            <span class="indexvalue">1</span>
            <span class="indexlabel">one</span>
        </div>
        <div class="amount">
            <span class="indexvalue">2</span>
            <span class="indexlabel">two</span>
        </div>
        <div class="amount">
            <span class="indexvalue">2</span>
            <span class="indexlabel">two</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
Generated:<br>
<div class="filters">
    <div class="options">
    </div>
</div>
```

NB: it was not clear what `this` was in `$(this).find(".filters .options")`, so I replaced it with `document` for this snippet to be runnable.